# Command Prompt Window closes after executing selection

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have successfully made a batch to pretty much do everything I want now how do I get the Command prompt window to remain open after execution for further input?

```css
pushd %~dp0
@ECHO OFF
cls
title XNB NODE
:home
echo.
echo What would you like to do?
echo =============
echo.
echo 1) Extract all XNB files and output to YAML folder
echo 2) Pack all YAML files and output to XNB folder
echo 3) Exit
echo.
set /p web=Type option:
if "%web%"=="1" xnb_node.cmd extract Xnb Yaml
if "%web%"=="2" xnb_node.cmd pack Yaml Xnb
if "%web%"=="3" exit
goto home
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have done.

Comment: `CMD` as a file extension normally indicates that the file is also a batch file (supported only in Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista or later). Try inserting the `CALL` command right before `xnb_node.cmd`, e.g., `call xnb_node.cmd pack Yaml Xnb`.

Comment: The CALL command did the trick!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [`call` command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php) when you execute other batch files if you don't want the interpreter to abort the parent batch program.

From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx):

> Calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch program. The call command accepts labels as the target of the call. Call has no effect at the command-line when used outside of a script or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if "%web%"=="1" xnb_node.cmd extract Xnb Yaml
if "%web%"=="2" xnb_node.cmd pack Yaml Xnb
if "%web%"=="3" exit
```

to

```
if "%web%"=="1" xnb_node.cmd extract Xnb Yaml && cmd /k && exit
if "%web%"=="2" xnb_node.cmd pack Yaml Xnb cmd /k && exit
if "%web%"=="3"  cmd /k && exit
```

It is not very good to use it this way, you may encounter some issues with title of the command prompt window and some other stuff, so I recommend using `CALL` command as Adam Morgan said.